# Transição com fade entre sprites

Tags: css

Eu tenho um botão que é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando eu passar o mouse, quero que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok, por exemplo, posso usar:

```
.unidades:hover{background-position: center -49px;}
```

O problema é que aí eu não consigo fazer um efeito de **aparecer lentamente**, tipo `transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;`

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? se eu usar o `background-position` parece que tem um efeito de **fade**, que não é o que eu quero.

Comment: Quando você diz "aparecer lentamente", seria de invisível para visível, ou "andando" de uma imagem para a outra?

Comment: De invisível para visível, utilizando o `transition`, de exemplo, que coloquei ali. Isso funciona com `background-color`, se eu usar com `background-image` ele não faz.

Comment: `background-image` [não é uma propriedade que possa ser animada](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). Tens que atualizar a pergunta com a tua _markup_ para se fazer algum ajuste à mesma de forma a simular a animação.

Comment: Você falando que o `backgroound-image` não pode ser animado, já resolveu meu problema. Vou ter que fazer com Jquery, fazer uma `div`, que quando eu passo o mouse em cima dela, apareça a outra `div` com a classe do `hover`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um exemplo simples com `button`:

```css
.opa, .opa span {
  position:relative;display:block;
  width:60px;height:60px;
  margin:0;padding:0;
  border:none;
}

.opa {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO1RB.jpg);
}
.opa span {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCrYi.jpg);
  transition: opacity .7s;
  opacity:0;
}

.opa:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="opa">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Não havia pensado em usar o `opacity`, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, eu fiz algo bem semelhante em um projeto meu. Ficou assim:

HTML

```
<div id="navLateral">
        <ul>
            <li class="item1">
                <a href="#">OP1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item2">
                <a href="#">OP2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item3">
                <a href="#">OP3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS3

```
#navLateral{
right: -70px;
position: fixed;
top: 300px;
z-index: 100;
}
#navLateral li{
background-color: #3e3e3e;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
list-style:none;
}
#navLateral li:hover{ margin-left: -80px; }
#navLateral a{
background-color: #3e3e3e;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 5px center;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
padding-left: 70px;
width: 130px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#navLateral .item1 a{ background-image: url(../images/suaimg.png); }
#navLateral .item2 a{ background-image: url(../images/suaimg.png); }
#navLateral .item3 a{ background-image: url(../images/suaimg.png); }
```

Espero ter ajudado.