# Como especificar um tempo na troca de cores com o :hover?

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="#">link</a>

a:hover{
 color:blue;
}
```

Com esse script eu consigo alterar a cor do texto "link" quando o mouse passa em cima, mas a cor é alterada instantaneamente. Eu queria que a troca de cores fosse suave, um pouco lenta. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta usar `transition`:

```
transition: color .7s;

              ^    ^--- tempo que vai durar
              |
               -- propriedade que quer suave
```

**Atenção** para um detalhe: no seu caso (e na maioria deles) você vai aplicar o `transition` no ítem original, não no afetado pelo `:hover`.

Se quiser com imagens, tem um exemplo aqui:

> [Transição com *fade* entre *sprites*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37676/70)

## Demonstração:

```css
a{
  color:red;
  transition: color .7s;
}

a:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Faça o hover aqui neste link</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!